# VB word 2013 on MAC: Open Safari, google text which is highlighted

Tags: macos

Is there anyone who can help me please.

**VB word 2013 on MAC: Open Safari, google text which is highlighted**

I have been trying for days to program VB code (in MS word 2013) to check whether PC or MAC, and if MAC then open Safari with a google search on the selected text in WORD.

The PC part works fine, and I am not used to MACs !!

Sub GoogleFetch()

```
 'Ctrl+G   Sub GoogleFetch()       ' Launch selected text on Google

runBrowser = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

mysite = "http://www.google.com/#q="
```

If Len(Selection) = 1 Then Selection.Words(1).Select

```
mysubject = Trim(Selection)

mysubject = Replace(mysubject, "&", "%26")

mysubject = Replace(mysubject, " ", "+")


#If Mac Then

    OpenURL mysite & mysubject

#Else

    Shell runBrowser & " " & mysite & mysubject

#End If
```

End Sub

Private Sub OpenURL(ByVal URL As String)

```
Dim s As String

s = "tell application ""Safari""" + vbCrLf + _

    "open location """ + URL + """" + vbCrLf + _

    "end tell"

MacScript s
```

End Sub

I receive an Execution error [5] on the Mac computer when it gets to MacScript s

Cannot work out why ??

Do I need to set any references in TOOLS, REFERENCES  like I would do on a PC ?

And if so, which references ?

Thank you for any help you may be able to offer.

Happy New Year 2018 as well !!

Comment: I should have added in my post that I have tried the following:

Comment: I should have added in my post that I have tried the following: Writing out line by line....... tell application "Safari"    then OPEN LOCATION, specifying the webpage, and then on the last line End Tell.  The compiler shows an error on the first line.....tell application "Safari"